# What does a normal variable defined inside a Ruby class mean?

Tags: ruby, variables

From what I understand, in Ruby class variables are preceded with `@@` while instance variables are preceded with `@`. But what does it mean if they're defined inside a class body without being preceded with anything?

```
class MyClass
  some_var = 'hello'
end
```

What does `some_var` refer to in this case?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23438728/ruby-instance-variables-or-local-variables

Comment: @brito I don't think so... It shares some information, but this is a very specific question and might yield some more in-depth answers.

Comment: `some_var` is a local variable (local to the class `MyClass`). Want proof?  Add `puts binding.local_variables` as the last line of the class definition. After `end` is executed it will print `"some_var"`.  (See [Kernel#binding](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-binding).)  Note that instances of the class `MyClass` will not see `some_var`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a local variable. See the official documentation about "[Local variables](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/UsersGuide/rg/localvars.html)".

Local variables, when declared within the scope of a Class, get evaluated whenever the class is loaded. Try to run this:

```
class MyClass
    bad_idea = 1/0

    def initialize
        puts "this is silly #{bad_idea}"
    end
end

puts "I told you this wouldn't work!"
```

You'll get a `ZeroDivisionError: divided by 0` and `"I told you this wouldn't work!"` will never get printed.

Comment: Thanks, Now I feel stupid, LOL.  But when does it get evaluated? When the class itself is created?

Comment: I think your question is quite intersting... Classes in Ruby are different from classes in, say, Java. A class is an object stored in a constant, which means it is open to changes in the runtime. I do not know how your example will behave (like, can you change that variable in any way during runtime?), but I'd like to know